# Swift : Expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time; consider breaking the expression into distinct sub-expressions

Tags: swift

I am new to Swift programming language. I am having a doubt while parsing json. My definition for parameters in json is as follows

```
let params  = [
   ["name":"action", "value":"pay"],
   [
      "name":"cartJsonData",
      "value":[
         "total":1,
         "rows":[
            [
               "quantity":"1000",
               "title":"Donation for SMSF India - General Fund",
               "price":"1",
               "itemId":"DN001",
               "cost":"1000",
               "currency":"INR"
            ]
         ]
      ]
   ],
   ["name":"center", "value":"Chennai"],
   ["name":"flatNumber", "value":"503"],
   ["name":"panNumber", "value":""],
   ["name":"payWith", "value":"CreditCard"],
   ["name":"reminderFrequency", "value":"Monthly"],
   ["name":"shipToAddr1", "value":"null"],
   ["name":"shipToAddr2", "value":"null"],
   ["name":"shipToCity","value":"null"],
   ["name":"shipToCountryName", "value":"India"],
   ["name":"shipToEmail",  "value":"raoa@hotmail.com"],
   ["name":"shipToFirstName","value":"Barnie"],
   ["name":"shipToLastName","value":"Killian"],
   ["name":"shipToPhone", "value":"8754470650"], 
   ["name":"shipToState", "value":"Telangana"], 
   ["name":"shipToZip", "value":"500001"], 
   ["name":"userId", "value":"test_id"],
   ["name":"shipToCountry", "value":"IN"]
]
```

I am getting the above error on this. Can someone explain on this?

Comment: Either do what the compiler is telling you in the error message, or declare explicitly the right type for this dictionary, so that the compiler doesn't have to infer it by itself. And please search before asking, this question has been asked and answered many times already. Thank you.

Comment: Nice. You're welcome. You can post your solution as an answer if you want. Or if you think there's a good duplicate somewhere on the site, you can flag your question as a duplicate of this link - it helps future users with similar issues to find their way towards a solution. These are only suggestions, of course. Thanks!

Comment: Regardless of your question, why don't you just use a `struct` instead of all those dictionaries with identical keys?

Comment: May be it was the other way around. I tried using this from the first. So keeping it as the same. struct will be very useful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the answer for the question. I made some changes to the declaration.

let params : [[String : AnyObject]]  = [["name" : "action", "value" : "pay" ],["name" : "cartJsonData" , "value" :  "{\"total\": 1,\"rows\":[{\"quantity\": \"(amount)\" ,\"title\": \"Donation for SMSF India - General Fund\",\"price\":\"1\",\"itemId\":\"DN001\",\"cost\": \"(amount)\",\"currency\":\"INR\"}]}"], ["name" : "center", "value" : "Chennai"], ["name" : "flatNumber", "value" : "503"], ["name" : "panNumber", "value" : "(pan)"], ["name" : "payWith"], ["name" : "reminderFrequency","value" : "Monthly"],  ["name" : "shipToAddr1"], ["name" : "shipToAddr2"], ["name" : "shipToCity"], ["name" : "shipToCountryName" , "value" : "India"], ["name" : "shipToEmail", "value" : "(email!)"], ["name" : "shipToFirstName" , "value": "(name!)"], ["name" : "shipToLastName"], ["name" : "shipToPhone", "value" : "(mobile!)"], ["name" : "shipToState"], ["name" : "shipToZip"], ["name" : "userId", "value" : "(userid)"], ["name" : "shipToCountry", "value" : "IN"]]